# Proving $\forall x\forall y Fxy ∴ \exists xFxx$

Tags: logic

> Construct a proof for the argument:
> $$\forall x\forall y Fxy ∴ \exists xFxx$$

I try to start with Fay universal instantiation

But proof-checker keeps telling me im wrong?

I'm not really sure how to start this proof

I have to do the proof on proof-checker.org

These are the rules im allowed to use:

- modus ponens  ->E
- modus tollens MT
- modus tollendo ponens DS
- double negation   DNE
- addition  vI
- adjunction    ^I
- simplification    ^E
- bicondition   <->I
- equivalence   <->E
- repeat    Rep
- conditional derivation    ->I
- reductio ad absurdum  RAA
- universal instantiation   AE
- universal derivation  AI
- existential instantiation EE
- existential generalization    EI

Comment: I find your series of logic questions and the proof-checker tool interesting, and I started to look into your questions first on [$P\wedge(Q\vee R)\therefore (P\wedge Q)\vee (P\wedge R)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4499435/89922) and then on [$\neg(R\vee S), P\to R, Q\to S\therefore \neg(P\vee Q)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4499497/89922) before you deleted them. Surely the formatting has room for improvement, but why do you keep deleting fine questions as soon as you solved them?

Comment: Deleting answered questions is generally bad. You should really respond to @peterwhy 's question.

Comment: I deleted them because none helped me.
If I figured out my own question, why would I leave up the question and waste time for someone else to try and figure it out?

Comment: Is the statement you're trying to prove written correctly? My formal logic is not strong, but it looks unprovable or false to me.

Comment: Yes it's written correctly

Comment: I was trying with the tool and found proofs for both of the previous questions, but typing and formatting in this site took time. If the questions would disappear randomly, why should I waste time to try and figure future questions out?

Comment: @D.Dmitriy My guess is, the OP is using a system which implicitly assumes the domain of discourse is nonempty.  Indeed, if you allowed for an empty domain of discourse, the sequent would not be valid.

Comment: Thanks @WoodsStashGang, I see that you undeleted one previous question. Maybe you will be able to [accept your answers and resolve these questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @WoodsStashGang - If you figure out an answer to your own question, it is 100% permitted to post the answer to your question, and it's actual the politest way to deal with it. Let others enjoy the results of your work too!

Answer (score 2):

Okay so the problem was trying to start with $Faa$.

*Solution:*

1. Premise = $\forall x \forall y Fxy$
2. $\forall y Fay$ 1 Universal instantiation
3. $Faa$  2 Universal instantiation
4. $\exists x Fxx$  3 Existential generalization